# Use Joomla! or start from scratch?

Tags: php, mysql, web, joomla

I have a new project to accomplish. It is mainly a static website with four or five different pages (photo gallery, contact info, etc.) and the client have asked for a CMS in order to manage the articles of the site and to build it multilingual (about 4-5 different languages).

My question is: should I use a CMS like Joomla! (I say Joomla because it is something I have already worked with, at least I know a few things) or build it from scratch with pure PHP and MySQL (I'm very familiar with both of them) ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Also, if you're downvoting, please leave a comment with the reasons. I would like to know your opinion.

Comment: The down votes are because the question appears to be asking for opinions and therefore is not a stackoverflow type of question... http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The main concern I have is if Joomla! can be used as a reliable, professional solution. Maybe I didn't express my question correctly...

Answer (score 2):

There this saying of "You don't reinvent the wheel".

That being said, if you already know Joomla and worked with it, it should be faster if you use it. Sure, you can build it from scratch if you want, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because in this way I will have full control on every aspect, even the slightest detail.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but this has been done before, and it would be rather pointless to do your own implementation. If you are confident you can do it faster than using presets in Joomla, go for it.